# laravel 9 show image and ip of user

Tags: php, laravel

I made a user corner in the administration panel, I try to display their data and so that I can crud there.

Admin user blade

```
@extends('superadmin.layouts.app')
@section('stylesheets')
    <style>
        .thread-parent {
            position: relative;

        }

        .thread-child {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            top: 10%;
            left: 24%;
        }

        .card-inner{
            position: relative;
        }

        .fa-window-close{
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .child{
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    </style>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container thread-parent">
        <table class="table" id="example1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Id</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Image</th>
                    <th scope="col">Secret word</th>
                    <th scope="col">Thread</th>
                    <th scope="col">Messages</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- <a href="{{ route('threads.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:showBlockBox({{ $user->id }})" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="z-index: 999"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></a>
                            --><a href="{{ route('user.destroy', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a> 
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->image }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->secretword }}</td>
                        <td>thread</td>
                        <td>Message</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function() {
            // $("#example1").DataTable({
            //     "responsive": true,
            //     "lengthChange": false,
            //     "autoWidth": false,
            //     "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
            // }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');

            $('#example1').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "responsive": true,
            });
        });

        function showBlockBox(threadid){
            $('.thread-child').show();
            $('#threadid').val(threadid);
        }

        function hideBlockBox(){
            $('.thread-child').hide();
            $('#threadid').val("");
        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

What I would like is to display the user image, but I don't know why its showing me /tmp/phpwO1DWI instead of the user image, I have this first problem. My second problem is that I would like to display the user's ip address in a th ip I tried to find a tutorial how to do it I can't find it. Could someone tell me how to display the image of the user and his ip address?

Comment: You probably saved the wrong image path in your database

Comment: @brombeer check there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487220/laravel-9-register-dont-work-page-refresh/73487556#73487556 have all my code for upload picture